# holomorphic map determined by a base-point free linear system

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm studying Miranda's book [Algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces]. I have a question about the base-point free linear systems. In chapter 5, proposition 4.15 of the text, the author explained the following fact:

Let $Q\subset |D|$ be a base-point free linear system of dimension $n$ on a compact Riemann surface  (i.e., $\forall p\in X$, $\exists E\in |D|,~ E(p)\neq 0$. ). Then there exists a holomorphic map $\phi: X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ such that $|\phi|=Q$.

The proof is as follows: Since $|D|$ has a natural bijective correspondence with $\mathbb{P}(L(D))$, we suppose that $Q$ corresponds to the pullback subspace $V\subset L(D)$ of dimension $n+1$. Now it suffices to choose a basis of $V$, say $\{f_0,...,f_n\}$; the map given by $\phi:=[f_0:...:f_n]$ is what we want here.

The author gives a rather concise sketch here and says "we've been running around these ideas enough now that the proof of the proposition is almost easier than the statement".

But I'm puzzled here: this concrete construction doesn't use the condition "$Q$ is base-point free". That is, for an arbitrary linear system you can still repeat this process to obtain a certain $\phi$. (Am I right? I'm not very sure!) The conclusion $|\phi|=Q$ is impossible now, but I can't see why it doesn't hold. Can anybody point out what I have missed? (By the way, I am also curious about the geometric picture/intuition of these abstract notions: linear systems, base points, etc.) Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti if $Q$ has a base point at $p$, then $ord_p(f_i)+D(p)>0$ for all $i$. But how does this imply $f_i(p)=0$?

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti Furthermore, Miranda wrote a lemma in the text that any such $[f_0:...:f_n]$ can be extended to their common zeroes in a natural way. This makes me more confused.

Comment: I have edited $E(p)=0$ to $E(p)\neq 0$ in your definition of base point free, which I think is the correct definition.

Comment: @Mohan thanks for editing, but on page 157 of the text by Miranda, he defined in definition 4.7: $p$ IS a base-point of a linear system $Q$ if $\forall E\in Q,~E\geq p$. So are we talking about the same thing? I think the nonzero condition is for "base point", not "base point free"?

Comment: OK, I remove my initial comment because I think I am confused by the notation. Now it seems to me that $E(p)$ means the coefficient of $p$ in the divisor $E$. Is that correct?

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti Oh yes, and now I think I understand what's the key point. In fact we have already used the base-point-free condition: cf. this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3670287/689494. The point is: for linear systems WITH base points, you can still define a map in this way, but the associated linear system of that map is not the original one! :)